# onOptionsItemSelected is not called so I can't go to next page intent

Tags: android

I want to ask I want to set menu add button on header of page, I already create icon menu layout and set it into java, but when I run it, it can't do a job inside that button (like validators and intent). I already try to debug but it not passed on breakpoint. Here is the image and the code.

[button on header of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQbfh.png)

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tambah, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.btn_tambah:
                boolean isValidatorsPassed = true;

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etNamaDokter.getText().toString())) {
                    isValidatorsPassed = false;

                    etNamaDokter.setError("Harap isi nama dokter");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etTanggalLahirDokter.getText().toString())) {
                    isValidatorsPassed = false;

                    etTanggalLahirDokter.setError("Harap isi tanggal lahir dokter");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etNoHp.getText().toString())) {
                    isValidatorsPassed = false;

                    etNoHp.setError("Harap isi nomor HP / telepon rumah dokter");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etJadwalPraktek.getText().toString())) {
                    isValidatorsPassed = false;

                    etJadwalPraktek.setError("Harap isi jadwal praktek dokter yang bersangkutan");
                }

                if (isValidatorsPassed) {
                    String namaDokter, tanggalLahirDokter, noHpDokter, jadwalPraktekDokter;

                    namaDokter = etNamaDokter.getText().toString();
                    tanggalLahirDokter = etTanggalLahirDokter.getText().toString();
                    noHpDokter = etNoHp.getText().toString();
                    jadwalPraktekDokter = etJadwalPraktek.getText().toString();

                    Intent intentBarcodeGenerator = new Intent(TambahDokterActivity.this, BarcodeGeneratorActivity.class);
                    intentBarcodeGenerator.putExtra("nama dokter", namaDokter);
                    intentBarcodeGenerator.putExtra("tanggal lahir", tanggalLahirDokter);
                    intentBarcodeGenerator.putExtra("no hp", noHpDokter);
                    intentBarcodeGenerator.putExtra("jadwal praktek", jadwalPraktekDokter);
                }

                return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the conditions actually match?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I know what happens. It happens may be android studio error, because when I invalidate and restart, it running normally or it should be.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to start the intent

you code will be like that.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tambah, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.btn_tambah:
                boolean isValidatorsPassed = true;

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etNamaDokter.getText().toString())) {
                    isValidatorsPassed = false;

                    etNamaDokter.setError("Harap isi nama dokter");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etTanggalLahirDokter.getText().toString())) {
                    isValidatorsPassed = false;

                    etTanggalLahirDokter.setError("Harap isi tanggal lahir dokter");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etNoHp.getText().toString())) {
                    isValidatorsPassed = false;

                    etNoHp.setError("Harap isi nomor HP / telepon rumah dokter");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etJadwalPraktek.getText().toString())) {
                    isValidatorsPassed = false;

                    etJadwalPraktek.setError("Harap isi jadwal praktek dokter yang bersangkutan");
                }

                if (isValidatorsPassed) {
                    String namaDokter, tanggalLahirDokter, noHpDokter, jadwalPraktekDokter;

                    namaDokter = etNamaDokter.getText().toString();
                    tanggalLahirDokter = etTanggalLahirDokter.getText().toString();
                    noHpDokter = etNoHp.getText().toString();
                    jadwalPraktekDokter = etJadwalPraktek.getText().toString();

                    Intent intentBarcodeGenerator = new Intent(TambahDokterActivity.this, BarcodeGeneratorActivity.class);
                    intentBarcodeGenerator.putExtra("nama dokter", namaDokter);
                    intentBarcodeGenerator.putExtra("tanggal lahir", tanggalLahirDokter);
                    intentBarcodeGenerator.putExtra("no hp", noHpDokter);
                    intentBarcodeGenerator.putExtra("jadwal praktek", jadwalPraktekDokter);

                    startActivity(intentBarcodeGenerator); //Add this line here
                }

                return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```